# React with Docusign Clickwrap API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docusignapi

I followed this tutorial https://dev.to/tis-ventures-inc/api-world-hackathon-report-no-2-docusign-clickwrap-with-react-2imp and got my docusign clickwrap implemented. However on my form, I want to keep my submit button disabled until the end user clicks 'agree' on the docusign clickwrap iframe. Since the Docusign clickwrap is provided by Docusign, I cant seem to attach a listener to the 'agree' button to know when it was clicked to enable my form submit button.

Comment: where is your code? try putting relevant sections here so we can see the problem clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, there are easy to use callbacks on the `render()` function that allow you to respond when the user agrees or declines (if decline button is enabled).

The `agreement` passed to each of these callbacks has metadata on the `agreedOn` or `declinedOn` timestamps if needed.

A quick sample in React below (switched this to using hooks and running the snippet rather than injecting it as HTML):

```js
function App() {
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
      environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
      accountId: '...',
      clickwrapId: '...',
      clientUserId: '...',

      onMustAgree(agreement) {
        // Called when no users have previously agreed by the above client user ID for the most recent required Clickwrap version
      },

      onAgreed(agreement) {
        // Called when either 1) the clientUserId has previously agreed 2) the clientUserId has clicked agree and completed successfully
      },

      onDeclined(agreement) {
        // Called when the clientUserId has declined successfully
      }
    }, '#ds-clickwrap');
  }, []);

  return <div id="ds-clickwrap" />
}
```

```html
<script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMG thanks. I was searching around for the longest time.